# Deleting files with same using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Im totally newbie in shell script.
Im need compare file name in two directories and delete files with same name.

EG:

```
Directory1/
one
two
three
four

Directory2/
two
four
five
```

After run script the directories will be:

```
Directory1/
one
three

Diretory2/
five
```

Thanks

Comment: I've tried diff Directory1/ Directory2/ but it shows me singular files in each directory and not yhe duplicate files.

Comment: You just need to delete files with same name? Different files can have same names. Correct approach would be to use `cksum` or `md5` to identify if the files are indeed duplicates.

Comment: only same name its allright. the content its not important in my case. thaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test -f` tests if a file exists:

```
cd dir1
for file in *
do
    test -f ../dir2/$file && rm $file ../dir2/$file
done
cd ..
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
while read fname
do 
    rm -vf Directory{1,2}/"$fname"
done < <(sort 
              <(cd Directory1/ && ls) 
              <(cd Directory2/ && ls) | 
         uniq -d)
```

This assumes a number of things about the filenames, but it should get you there with the input shown, and similar cases.

Tested too, now:

```
mkdir /tmp/stacko && cd /tmp/stacko
mkdir Directory{1,2}
touch Directory1/{one,two,three,four} Directory2/{two,four,five}
```

Runnning the command shows:

```
removed `Directory1/four'
removed `Directory2/four'
removed `Directory1/two'
removed `Directory2/two'
```

And the resulting tree is:

```
Directory1/one
Directory1/three

Directory2/five
```

Comment: why double less than is used < < ?

Comment: `<` means input redirection, `<(cmd)` means process substitution (open the output of a command _like a file(descriptor)_); `< <(cmd)` therefore redirects input from a _pseudo-file_ (pipe) that represents the output of `cmd`.